# Why pyarrow write_dataset not keeping field metadata?

Tags: dataset, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm experimenting with a data transformation workflow and am getting stuck with trying to persist metadata within a parquet file. Here is a toy example showing a similar issue.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

# Define the Parquet output directory
parquet_output_path = "data/Parquet"

# Create a table schema with custom metadata
# Define schema with metadata
schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('id', pa.int64(), metadata={'description': 'ID of the record'}),
    pa.field('name', pa.string(), metadata={'description': 'Name of the person'}),
    pa.field('age', pa.int32(), metadata={'description': 'Age of the person'}),
])

# Create some test data
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35],
}

# Convert the data to a table
table = pa.Table.from_pydict(data, schema=schema)

# Convert the table to a dataset
dataset = ds.dataset([table])
dataset.schema
```

```
Output:
id: int64
  -- field metadata --
  description: 'ID of the record'
name: string
  -- field metadata --
  description: 'Name of the person'
age: int32
  -- field metadata --
  description: 'Age of the person'
```

Everything seems good so far :)

```
# Write the dataset to Parquet format with a custom filename template and schema
ds.write_dataset(
    dataset,
    parquet_output_path,
    format="parquet",
    basename_template="sample_{i}.parquet",
    schema=schema,
    existing_data_behavior="overwrite_or_ignore"
)
```

```
parquet_output_path = r'data\PARQUET\sample_0.parquet'

# Read the Parquet files back and check the schema and metadata
parquet_dataset = ds.dataset(parquet_output_path, format="parquet")
print(f"Overall dataset schema: {len(parquet_dataset.schema)} columns")
print(f"Overall dataset metadata: {parquet_dataset.schema.metadata}")
```

```
Overall dataset schema: 3 columns 
Overall dataset metadata:None
```

```
parquet_dataset.schema
```

```
id: int64
name: string
age: int32
```

What gives? I want to avoid materializing the entire dataset in memory so thought this would be a good option from what I've learned about arrow so far.

Comment: It seems with datasets it doesn't store those metadata directly in the files, instead you have to dump the metadata yourself using `pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata()`  (and manually read back that metadatafile). There's some hints to this at https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#writing-to-partitioned-datasets as well.

I don't quite see all the details regarding this, but a bit of quick testing shows that atleast your custom metatadata gets preserved when using `pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata()`

Answer (score 1):

Arrow doesn't persist the "dataset" in any way (just the data). and so the metadata on the dataset object is ignored during the call to write_dataset.  There is a slippery slope between "a collection of data files" (which pyarrow can read & write) and "a dataset with metadata" (which tools like Iceberg and Hudi define.)  There was some discussion on the topic in https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/30805 but nothing was done.

If you're interested in getting the metadata in the data files themselves then you could probably open an issue.  This is already possible in the C++ so it would just be a matter of adding python bindings.

The easiest workaround is probably to store the schema separately in its own file.  [`pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata.html) can do this for parquet or you can create an empty IPC file to store it with `pyarrow.ipc`.